# Android SDL2 resuming on lock screen

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, sdl, sdl-2

I have an android SDL2 project set up, when I go home the process pauses and resumes when I reopen the app like it should however if I lock the screen whilst having the app running in the foreground then the process will pause breifly then quickly resume and continue running whilst the screen is off. This does not happen if I run the app in portrait mode so it is resuming when the orientation changes from landscape to the lock screens portrait as it thinks it needs to run surfaceChanged.

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed to landscape instead of sensorLandscape and it works